# Get the parent key if a value is in the nested list (dict_values)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'7D': {'category': 'C', 'directory': 'C', 'name': 'Co'},
 '37': {'category': 'C', 'directory': 'C', 'name': 'FI'},
 'AA': {'category': 'F', 'directory': 'F', 'name': 'Le'},
 '80': {'category': 'Cl', 'directory': 'F', 'name': 'AV'},
 'F7': {'category': 'Cl', 'directory': 'F', 'name': 'AG'}}
```

I would like to get `7D` if `lookup_value = 'Co'`. I have tried these two approaches:

```
lookup_value = 'Co'
for name, val in groups.items():
    if val == lookup_value:
        print(name)
```

And this:

```
print(list(groups.keys().[list(groups.values()).index(lookup_value)])
```

The second one returns:

```
 ValueError: 'Co' is not in list
```

**Edit:**

I am sorry for this mess, I figured that the initial dictionary does not have a nested dictionary. It turns out that is a list as can be observed from the following:

```
bbb = groups.values()
type(bbb)
```

which returns `dict_values`. This turns out to be a list, as per Daniel F below!

Comment: You should name your variables

Comment: in the `for` loop? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant your initial dictionary, but from context, I guess you call it `groups`

Comment: yep! thanks for your answer below. let me try that out, will get back to you!

Comment: Maybe this would be of interest to you https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python#filtering (but it's an entire library just for that small task).

Comment: The thing with the `dict_values` being a "list" isn't helpful. The important thing is to see what is inside that list. What type the elements are of.

Comment: can you help me with further investigating this?

Comment: `type(groups.values())` has nothing to do with the actual type of your values, so your update is nonsense. Try `[type(v) for v in groups.values()]

Comment: Is a dictionary really the idea data structure for this? Considering the format and the operation you’re trying to perform, I would go for something tabular, like a DataFrame.

Comment: It's becoming clear at this point that you're working with code that differs significantly with what you posted here. Both answers are perfectly adequate for what you've actually posted. You can verify this with a simple copy and paste.

Comment: I agree and I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, dictionaries are for one-way lookup. If you find yourself doing a reverse lookup often, it's probably worth creating and maintaining a reverse dictionary:

```
groups = {...}
names = {v['name']: k for k, v in groups.items()}
```

Now it's as simple as accessing

```
names['Co']
```

If you really just want one lookup without creating the reverse dict, use `next` with a generator:

```
next(k for k, v in groups.items() if v['name'] == 'Co')
```

Comment: received `TypeError: 'Group' object is not subscriptable` for both options. is this unexpected?

Comment: @AK88. That just means that your initial object is not a dictionary

Comment: I ran this `type(groups)` and got `dict`. is it not dictionary?

Comment: `TypeError: 'Group' object is not subscriptable` means that you have a `Group` object, not `str`. I can't fix that for you without seeing a lot more info.

Comment: I am sorry for this confusion, looking into it now.

Comment: I have updated the OP. I would love to accept your answer if you can modify it. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I want to explain why your first approach does not work as intended and provide smallest-change repair.
Your `groups` is dict with keys being `str`s and values being `dict`s, thus inside your for-loop:

```
for name, val in groups.items():
```

`val` is `dict` for example: `{'category': 'C', 'directory': 'C', 'name': 'Co'}` and asking python about equality (`==`) between `str` and `dict` lead to response: No. Correct question: is `'Co'` inside `dict`'s values? After changing that, your code will be working:

```
lookup_value = 'Co'
for name, val in groups.items():
    if lookup_value in val.values():
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
7D
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but I am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: @AK88 apparently you `groups` variable is a `Group` Object (whatever that is) and not a `dict`. Does you real code differ from what you posted in the question? But reading your other comment, apparently it's not your `groups` variable which is of type `Group`, but the values of the groups items. --> so `groups` is a dict, but what is in the `groups`, those are not `dicts`. The things which follow the keys, those appear not to be `dicts`.

Comment: yes, it does. But pythonic type is `dict` though. So I thought this is a dictionary ... strange ...

Comment: @DanielF, thanks for helping out. I did look into the structure further and have this: `bbb = groups.values(); type(bbb)` which returns `dict_values`. Is this something different than dictionary?

Comment: `for name, val in groups.items(): print(type(val))` should print out `<type 'Group'>`. If that is the case, you need to find out what that `Group` object is.

Comment: `dict_values` is a `view object` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: Try the following: `groups = dict(groups)`, maybe that coerces the `Group` objects into becoming `dicts` while keeping the entire outer structure (it's not a clean solution).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204811/discussion-between-daniel-f-and-ak88).

Comment: Does `for name, val in groups.items(): print(val.name)` work? Are you using Django? Try `val.name`, and in the accepted answer, replace `v['name'] == 'Co'` with `v.name == 'Co'` if it works.